# How to find matrix eigenvectors using LR offset algorithm (first making it almost triangular)

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, programming

I want to evaluate eigenvalues and their eigenvectors using LR algorithm. I know how to solve first problem (values), that's exactly what LR does. But I also need to find eigenvectors using this method (programmatically).

1) Is it possible?

2) If it is, how to implement it?